# How to fix blank screen after deleting and re-installing my app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5

I am working on an app that requires users to log in or make an account to get to the main page. I used this code (below) in the SceneDelegate to basically tell the app that if the user is logged in, go to the main view controller, otherwise go to the login view controller. When the app is installed on a new device, this seems to work and once a user is logged in, the app takes them to the main view controller. However, I found that when the app is deleted and re-installed from a device, the app opens to a black view controller with an empty tab bar at the bottom. When I tried to debug by telling Xcode to print whether the app thinks it is signed in or not, in this case, it doesn't print that it's signed in OR out. Please let me know how to fix this if you know what the issue is. Heres the SceneDelegate code.

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    
    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

        if AuthManager.shared.isSignedIn {
            // signed in UI
            window.rootViewController = TabBarViewController()
            print("signed in")
        }
        else {
            // sign in ui
            let vc = SignInViewController()
            let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            window.rootViewController = navVC
            print("Sign IN")
        }

        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        self.window = window
    }

    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {

    }

    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {

    }

    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {

    }

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {

    }

    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint to see what is happening. Is the 'guard` statement returning?

Comment: So I figured out that when a user deletes the app and re-installs it, as long as they were never signed in the sign-in VC shows. When the blank VC shows is if the person had logged into the app before, then deleted it. When the issue occurs, I can see that the app still thinks it is logged in and so it shows the tab bar controller but there's no content for it to display. I have no idea how to fix this but now I know that the issue is that after re-installing the app, it still thinks it is logged in.

Comment: There is probably a value stored in the keychain. One strategy is to store a boolean in `UserDefaults` that is `true` after you have run for the first time. If this value is `false` then just show the logins screen even if `isSignedIn` is true

Comment: This fixed the issue so thank you! The way I did it also made it so that the user has to log in every time they open the app which was not originally how it was set up but I think it's ok and makes the app more secure.